# Attempted import error: 'GridActionsCellItem' is not exported from '@mui/x-data-grid'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to import 'GridActionsCellItem' from '@mui/x-data-grid' as:

```
import { GridActionsCellItem } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
```

But it shows error as:

```
Attempted import error: 'GridActionsCellItem' is not exported from '@mui/x-data-grid'.
```

I am copying the official documentation code from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wcdu3?file=/demo.js:32-98).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What version of x-data-grid do you have in your package.json ?

Comment: "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",

Comment: The documentation is using version"5.0.0-beta.2" -- the "next" version in npm as opposed to the "latest" version (which is "4.0.0"). `GridActionsCellItem` doesn't exist in version "4.0.0".

Comment: so, can u tell me how can i update to 5.0.0-bete.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by upgrading my '@mui/x-data-grid' from 4.4.to '5.0.0-beta.2'.
Just replace the version of your @mui/x-data-grid package in your package.json with ^5.0.0-beta.2 and it should work.

Comment: mui 5.0.1 is out, I would suggest moving off 5.0.0-beta.2 and use 5.0.1

Comment: @Alan `mui` and `mui/x-data-grid` are the different packages. 
`x-data-grid` is still 4.0.2